# How to remove a group of words from a character variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the character variable like below and I want to remove some words from that variable.

My data:

```
   variable
 1 "star war it ik ar"
 2 "jammu kashmir DO"
 3 "hey Ho dude"
 4 "time kya hi abhi"
 5 "every one ji"
 6 "thanks to iF everyone"
 7 "hey i am in america yo"
```

I want to remove some words and letters fro the variable.

Expected result:

```
   variable                 created_var
 1 "star war it ik ar"      "star war"
 2 "jammu kashmir DO"       "jammu kashmir"
 3 "hey Ho dude"            "hey dude"
 4 "time kya hi abhi"       "time kya abhi"
 5 "every one ji"           "every one"
 6 "thanks to iF everyone"  "thanks to everyone"
 7 "hey i am in america yo" "hey i am in america"
```

I tried the following:

```
waste <- c("it", "ik", "ar", "DO", "Ho", "hi", "iF", "yo")
data$created_var <- gsub(waste, "", data$variable)
```

The above code is working for a single word but not for the group of words. How can I remove all the words in `waste`?

Comment: Please consider to add a `dput(data)`.

Comment: @Pascal didn't get that, can you please elaborate.

Comment: Try `trimws(gsub(paste0('\\b(',paste(waste, collapse='|'), ')\\b'), '', df$variable))`